# After installing Nvidia the resolution changed to 640X480

Tags: nvidia, resolution

I visited the NVIDIA website downloaded the NVIDIA **NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.108.run** drivers. I stopped my  X server and terminated all OpenGL applications. I changed my run level to 3 so that it boot to VGA console and installed it. I successfully installed the driver, but after installing my resolution has changed to *640x480* and now I am stuck, and I can't access my sidebar.

I am a new user so I'll request a clear answer.

Comment: Are you trying to install in laptop which has Nvidia optimus ?

Comment: You can always scroll if the resolution is too low, go near a border and the screen will move in that direction, this way you can go to system settings and change your screen resolution, or install another driver.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure what you are asking, but it seems you are not able to use your computer because of a change in resolution. So my answer is based on this.
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal 
or
 <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `terminal`

This will open the terminal. There type

```
xrandr -s 0
```

If this doesn't work try

```
xrandr -s 1280x1024
```

If you just mean to ask how to change the resolution, press the super key ( window key) and type 'display' and click on the icon named display. There you can change the resolution.

Comment: Can you please add some more data about your problem...